# Is this proof of $f_{n} \to f$ iff $f_{n}(z) \to f(z)$ uniformly for $z$ on the trace of any closed rectifiable curves $\gamma$ in $G$ correct?

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove the following.

If $f, f_1, f_2, \dots$ are analytic functions on $G$ (an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$), then $\{f_{n}\} \to f$ (in the sense that $\{f_{n}\} \to f$ uniformly on all compact subsets of $G$) iff $f_{n}(z) \to f(z)$ uniformly for $z \in \{\gamma\}$ ($\gamma$ is an arbitrary closed and rectifiable curve in $G$).

What I have the $\impliedby$ direction:

Given any compact subset $K$ of $G$, we can find $r > 0$ and $a \in G$  such that $K \subseteq B(a, r) \subseteq G$. Now $\mathrm{dist}(K, \mathbb{C} \setminus G)>0$ (because $K$ is compact and $\mathbb{C} \setminus G$ is closed) implies that we can find some $R> r$ such that $K \subseteq B(a, R) \subseteq G$.

Let $C(a, R)$ denote the circle of radius $R$ centred at $a$.  For all $z \in K$ we have

\begin{align*}
 |f(z)-f_{n}(z)| &\le \frac{1}{2\pi}\biggl| \int_{C(a, R)} \frac{f(w)-f_{n}(w)}{w-z}\,d{w} \biggr| \\
 &\le \frac{1}{2\pi}\cdot 2\pi R \cdot \frac{1}{R-r} \cdot \sup \{|f(w)-f_{n}(w)| \mid w \in C(a, R)\}\\
 &=\frac{R}{R-r}\cdot \sup \{|f(w)-f_{n}(w)| \mid w \in C(a, R)\}\\
 & \to 0 \;\text{as}\;n \to \infty \quad \;\text{(follows by assumption)}\;
\end{align*}

Hence we have that $\{f_{n}\} \to f$ uniformly on $K$.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the idea of bounding $\sup_{z \in K}|f(z) - f_n(z)|$ by applying Cauchy's integral formula to a closed path in $G \setminus K$ that winds around $K$.

However, it's not true that you can take this closed path to be a circle. In your argument, you said that there exists an $a \in G$ and an $R > 0$ such that $K \subset B(a, R) \subset G$. A little bit of experimentation shows that this is not true. For example, consider the case where $K$ is a closed square centred at $0$ with sides of length $1$, and $G$ is an open square centred at $0$ with sides of length $1.00001$.

That said, your overall strategy is fine. You just need to be open to the possibility that the closed path that you integrate on might not be circular.

A really useful theorem to know is the following:

> If $K \subset G \subset \mathbb C$ with $K$ compact and $G$ open, then there exists a cycle $\Gamma$ in $G \setminus K$ such that the winding number of $\Gamma$ around any point in $K$ is equal to $1$. (A cycle is a finite union of closed paths.)

This is Theorem 13.5 in Rudin. The proof is surprisingly intuitive. You cover $\mathbb C$ with a sufficiently fine grid of squares - fine enough that every point in $K$ lies in a square that lies entirely within $G$. Then you construct the cycle $\Gamma$ by taking the edges of all the squares that intersect $K$, discarding edges from adjacent squares that cancel out.

In the picture below, I demonstrate this procedure in an example where $K$ has two connected components, one of which has a hole in the middle. The cycle $\Gamma$ consists of three closed paths: two anticlockwise paths that encircle the two connected components of the $K$, and a clockwise path inside the hole.

[image: contour]

Anyway, now that you have this cycle $\Gamma$ in $G \setminus K$ that winds once around each point in $K$, Cauchy's integral formula gives
$$ f(z) - f_n(z) = \frac {1}{2\pi i} \int_\Gamma \frac{f(w) - f_n(w)}{w - z} dw, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{for all } z \in K,$$
and you argue like in your original answer. (Note that the distance between $K$ and $\Gamma$ is a strictly positive number - something that you can prove using a compactness argument. You can then bound $1 / (w - z)$ by one over this distance.)